# Constant Current Led Driver (non dimmable) to work with PWM

Tags: led, pwm, driver, constant-current, dimming

I have 18W lamps that came with non dimmable led drivers. Ive found datasheet for the main chip (ws3441), which included schematics:

[image]
and internal block scheme of the chip:
[image]

I'd like to add dimming controlled with PWM - 1024 levels. I already have PWM part ready - used 6W lamps before successully. They also came with non dimable led drivers but I replaced power adapters to one one 20V with enogh power, which was not sensitive to the shorts in the circuit made by MOSFETs controled by microchip. For 18W lamps I cannot find right power adapter - 70V / >2A. Anyways, I plan to mount those lamps in different rooms so one adapter will not be enough. The best solution would be to make use of those drivers that came with lamps.
I've read a bit and searched over internet for solution, found few interesting topics, two of them below:

- [link 1](https://www.powerelectronics.com/lighting/how-add-analog-dimming-virtually-any-led-driver)
- [link 2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281849/pwm-dimming-using-the-tlc5916-current-limiting-led-driver)

but I dont know how to get use of that information to resolve my problem.
Basically Im taking following solutions into account:

- somehow disable current sensing and make it fixed (led driver will only be used with this one kind of lamp) so PWM can work properly,
- maybe using additional transformer like shown here would be solution?
  [image]

Here are photos of the driver:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you ask a clear answerable question?

Comment: The original circuit is non-isolated from the AC mains.  If you connect any additional circuitry to it without knowing exactly what you are doing you could create a serious safety hazard.

Comment: Question is, how to achieve dimming with available hardware? modifications are of course obvious but I'm not looking for answer "buy new driver".

Comment: *how to achieve dimming with available hardware?* Hmm, these drivers are made to a (low) price, the components that are there are to make it do what it does, no more, no less. Generally a driver suitable for dimming is more expensive because it has different (and possibly more) components. If it was easily possible to make a dimmable driver from the non-dimmable design then you would be able to buy those already. So the only answer possible is: buy a new driver.

Comment: what about ideas from attached links?

Comment: and as for available dimming capable drivers, I've found ones with 256 lvls. As I mentioned I use and need 1024.

Comment: I'd like to see exactly what you actually did where you wrote, *"I'd like to add dimming controlled with PWM - 1024 levels. I already have PWM part ready - used 6W lamps before successully. They also came with non dimable led drivers but I replaced power adapters to one one 20V with enogh power, which was not sensitive to the shorts in the circuit made by MOSFETs controled by microchip."* What precisely did you modify and how did you modify it for your \$6\:\text{W}\$ version?

Comment: 6W led panels require 20V. So i got rid of those non dimmable cheap drivers and used 20V power adapter along with microchip giving PWM signals to MOSFETs. Thats it. Now its exactly the same except that new 18W panels need 70V and there is no power adapter like that, at least I haven't found one. So I didnt modify drivers before.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a dimmer to that fixed output LED driver you are using.

You need to buy another LED driver with a dimmer input.

I would recommend an [HLG-40H-xxB](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/HLG-40H/HLG-40H-spec.pdf) where xx = the maximum forward voltage. If the LEDs forward voltage is greater than 54V then a [HLG-60H-C](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=HLG-60H-C)  will do the job.

An HLG type B can be dimmed with a resistance, 0-10vdc, or PWM.

Comment: this driver is worth 10 times the LED panel... I've decided to take few panels apart and change it to 12V, so they can be powered and controlled by existing instalation.

Comment: That driver, new, cost maybe $5.  I don't think it is "worth" that much.  For the one pictured, I would not give you $1 for it.  I would not buy a new one at $5.  Why 12V?  I know nothing about any panel.  This is the first mention of a "panel".   https://www.aliexpress.com/item/LED-External-Driver-300mA-18-24-x1W-DC-60V-84V-Led-Driver-18W-20W-21W-22W/32810172471.html

Comment: HLG-40 is for 40W and cant suply constant current panel (30x leds in one line) properly.

Comment: @eri 
Do you know anyone that would want to drive 30 LEDs in series?  That's a forward voltage of about 90 volts.  It's not about the wattage.  A 40 Watt driver can easily drive a long series string of LEDs.  You must consider both forward voltage and current desired.
If you did, an HLG-60H-C350 would do the job well.  It has an output of 100-200 VDC and up to 350 mA. 
I generally drive LED strips with a 40 V forward voltage.

Comment: 40 Watt driver at cunstant current mode makes 700mA but one module at 60-90V. One module needs 300mA and will burn at 700mA) It ok for 2 lines, but 2 lines is too much. 

I have 10W 150 mA (in LED) lamp on my table and i cant dim it to 5W. I did not found constant current suply with PWM,SPI,DMX, etc.  I have 18W 300mA near bed - i turn lamp to ceiling )

Comment: Cheapest way to is to trash this lamps and buy new like Philips Hue.